# flutter commands arent Running in my command prompt, when i write flutter,i waited for an hour still didnt show anything im using win 10 pro, i tryed

Tags: flutter, cmd, windows-10, command-prompt, flutter-doctor

i formatted my pc windows 10 , i installed window 10 pro and installed java jdk v 11, also visual studio installer, vs code android studio, all possible solutions for not recognizing flutter or flutter doctor issues, my cmd is working properly but when i write flutter i wat for hours and see nothing , my path in env variables is :C:\Program Files\flutter\bin

also seen this in my vs code terminal:
[vs code terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls72h.jpg)
[pc terminal did nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLUKl.png)

Comment: Did you set the system environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because: According to the Fluter [document](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows), one of the warnings is that Flutter should not be in the **Program File**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzwKL.png)

solution: Convert Flutter Location to `C:\src\flutter`and also change the path in the env to `C:\src\flutter\bin`

For better Understanding check the Flutter [Documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows)

Comment: fixed!!! :) thank you, i updated the path to C:\src\flutter\bin in system environment variables